# PowerShell: Using Out-File to write specific part of Dir listing to a text file

Tags: powershell

So I know how to use Out-File to write a full directory listing to a text file, but my issue is that I want to write only certain parts of the directory to the file, i.e., I only want to write the directory name, the file name, the length of the file, and the last write time.

Here is what I have tried:

*I use the "~" as a delimeter.*

```
cls

$Path = "C:\Testpath"
$OutFile = "C:\Testpath\Output.txt"

gci -Path $Path -Recurse | % { $_.Directory + "~" + $_.Name + "~" + $_.Length + "~" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") } | Out-File $Outfile
```

It seems to create the file and write a few lines, then I get this error multiple times until the script finishes. The only few lines that were written seem to be the subfolders within the parent folder.

**Error:**

```
+ : Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

At C:\SomeDirectory.ps1:4 char:46
+ gci -Path $Path -Recurse | % { $_.Directory + <<<<  "~" + $_.Name + "~" + $_.Length + "~" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") } | Out-File $Outfile
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

**Note:** I replaced my actual location with C:\SomeDirectory in the error for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
$Path = "C:\Testpath"
gci -Path $Path | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | ft -AutoSize
```

You can see that there are different sets of properties for

- TypeName: `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`:

  - no `.Directory` property: use `.PSParentPath.Remove(0,38)` or  `.PSParentPath.Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::', '')` instead (not found smarter substitution);
  - no `.Length` property: use `"-0"` or whatever else;
- TypeName: `System.IO.FileInfo`:

  - use `.DirectoryName` property (type `string`) rather than `.Directory` one (type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`).

Here is my *dummy* solution:

```
$Path = "C:\Testpath"
$OutFile = "C:\Testpath\Output.txt"

gci -Path $Path -Recurse | % { 
    if ($_.Attributes -match "Directory") {
        $_.PSParentPath.Remove(0,38) + "~" + $_.Name + "~" + "-0" + "~" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
    } else {
        $_.DirectoryName + "~" + $_.Name + "~" + $_.Length + "~" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
    }
} | Out-File $Outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert Directory to string:

```
$_.Directory.ToString()
```

Comment: That seemed to work a bit (it wrote a bunch of lines to the file, but hard to tell right now if it wrote everything), but I got a new error: `ToString : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: @chrisdoubleu13 you need to make a **null check before you use a variable**. Just a good practice buddy. Also, that is a separate question. majkinetor resolved the question you originally asked. I believe if your original problem is resolved you can very well accept this as answer. I am upvoting this answer. Let us know if you still face the same error. You can always open another question if you face different error while working and after you have tried searching for answer.